# Remote code execution after tmux reboot

Tags: ssh, tmux, nohup

I've read about `tmux-resurrect`, but it's still not clear to me if I can do the following:

1. start `tmux` session
2. `ssh` to remote server
3. launch long-running code on remote host
4. kill tmux server (e.g. local machine reboot)
5. restore & reattach tmux session (e.g. using `tmux-resurrect`)
6. continue monitoring the code I launched on the remote server

Do I need to use `nohup` in step 3? or can `tmux-resurrect` (or some other tool) take care of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No local-side tool can do this, because of what the server "sees":

- if you disconnect SSH gracefully, the server will notice this immediately;
- if you just disappear (e.g. by a hard reset), the connection will stay open on the server side until some kind of timeout (compare `ClientAlive*` options, TCP keepalive concept – see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1283733/432690) for some details).

Even if you intended to use `tmux-resurrect` or another tool on the local side, the server doesn't know, doesn't care. It will terminate your long-running code unless you used `nohup` or better…

**If you can, use `tmux` (or `screen`) on the server**:

1. Don't enter `tmux` session on the client.
2. `ssh` to the server.
3. Start `tmux` session on the server.
4. Launch long-running code there.
5. Disconnect anyhow: gracefully or not, with or without detaching from the remote `tmux`.
6. `ssh` again.
7. Your `tmux` session is still there (unless something bad happened to the server in the meantime); reattach with `tmux a`.

I use `tmux` this way on daily basis and I think this is the right way. On my laptop `tmux` sessions last for few hours at most, I shut it down every night; but I have access to a couple of servers where my `tmux` sessions run for months. When I'm writing this, on one of them there's `watch df -h` process running literally for a week in a `tmux` session started like two months ago.

Comment: Wow, this is brilliant, and so obvious in retrospect :)