# Is there a way to have a dynamic system status area in the Linux terminal that updates while one does something else?

Tags: linux, terminal, unix

I'm thinking for some servers I look after, that after I SSH in to the box it would be very helpful to see things like disk usage, CPU usage and the such in the actual terminal I'm in as I’m working. Not just a static bit of data displayed once MOTD.

Yes, I understand that I can just issue a command like top but i'd like a header or footer area with just a couple lines that show some info to me and be shown the entire time I'm working. A dynamic area that continues to do it's job as I work.

Anyone heard of such a thing?

Comment: What OS are you in  when you connect? You can split windows and even set tabs in macOS.

Comment: Update: misread the question.  I'm usually in a cygwin session on a Windows box

Comment: Fair enough. Kamil’s answer seems to be the best solution then.

Answer (score 2):

Use `tmux` to split your terminal into panes (alternative: GNU `screen`). Then run whatever you want wherever you want.

The below screenshot was taken, while `iotop`, `htop`, `watch df -h` and `watch sensors` were constantly running. There is also one shell (could be more if I wanted) waiting for commands.

[image: tmux]

Working with `tmux` is my daily routine; no matter if in tty, terminal emulator under X11, connecting with `ssh` from another Linux or with PuTTY from Windows.

When connecting via SSH, I prefer running `tmux` on a server, so I can detach (disconnect) at any time and attach later to my tasks still running (compare [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1288659/432690) and my answer there).

If you cannot install `tmux` on your server(s), run it locally and connect to the server (or different servers) from each pane separately. In this case some of your remote tasks will die if you disconnect, as if you didn't use `tmux` (no wonder, from the server's point of view you don't use `tmux`), still your local console will be able to show separate panes with local or remote programs running.