# How to redirect output to file and print pid to screen with nohup

Tags: linux, bash

I am using `nohup` to run a script and redirect its output to a file. The command I am running looks somewhat like this:

```bsh
nohup script.sh > output.log
```

This works fine, but what I now want is to be able to also print the PID of the process running `script.sh` to the console when I execute the `nohup` command.

This is mainly to make killing the processes easier. Running `jobs` does not show anything.

I will be grateful if anyone tells me how I can achieve this. Start script with `nohup`, redirect output to a file and then print the PID to the screen.

Comment: `I am using nohup to run a script and redirect its output to a file` – Note you don't need `nohup` to do *exactly* this. [`nohup` is for other things](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3886/108618). "How to find out the PID of `script.sh`?" is a valid question with or without `nohup`. Usage of `nohup` may invalidate some solutions if `nohup` doesn't replace itself with `script.sh` (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

#### Jobs and P(G)IDs

> ```
> nohup script.sh > output.log
> ```
>
> […]
>
> This is mainly to make killing the processes easier. Running `jobs` does not show anything.

The command you used runs `nohup` synchronously. The shell will not run the next command (e.g. `jobs`) until after `script.sh` exits. Even if `script.sh` runs some command(s) asynchronously and exits, the command(s) will not be considered a job in your current shell. Invoking `jobs` in another shell during the execution of `script.sh` cannot show you the script because each shell has its own list of jobs.

Run `nohup` asynchronously in the first place:

```
nohup script.sh > output.log &
```

If job control is enabled (in an interactive Bash it is enabled by default, unless the OS doesn't support it), you will see something like

```
[3] 31421
```

where `31421` is the PID you're after. Then `jobs` (and `jobs -l`, `jobs -p`) will work. With or without job control enabled, the PID will be available as `$!`. Invoking another asynchronous process or `bg` will change the value of `$!`, so consider saving the PID right away:

```
nohup script.sh > output.log &
pid="$!"
```

The shell will know the PID of `nohup`, not necessarily of `script.sh`; but most likely `nohup` will replace itself with `script.sh` without creating a new PID. (I think this behavior is not strictly required for `nohup`; still common implementations do this). In your case this means that `kill "$pid"` will send `SIGTERM` which will be delivered to `nohup` before `script.sh` is started, or to `script.sh` after it is started.

`SIGTERM` is the default signal. You can choose `SIGINT`: `kill -s INT "$pid"`. In this answer I will stick to `SIGTERM` only to avoid repeating `-s INT` all the time.

Note sending a signal to the script will not automatically send it to its children.

If job control is enabled, Bash will run each command (it may be a pipeline) in a separate process group. In your case the process group ID (PGID) will be the PID of `nohup`. The right way to kill the entire process group is to send `SIGTERM` to the group:

```
kill -- "-$pid"
```

where `-` before the PID tells `kill` to address the group, not just one process (and then [`--` is a must](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618)). This will kill descendants of `script.sh` even after the script itself exits (excluding descendants deliberately run with another PGID, if any). This, however, is not as robust as you may wish. It may happen the process group you want to kill is long gone and the same number is reused for some new group. In such case you can inadvertently address the wrong group.

In Bash the `kill` *builtin* accepts jobspecs. `kill %3` (where `3` is taken from `[3]` in `[3] 31421` or from the output of `jobs`) will send `SIGTERM` to the right process group. A jobspec may look like `%3` or `%nohup` or `%nohup script.sh` (with the space escaped or quoted, e.g. `'%nohup script.sh'`); so this command:

```
kill '%nohup script.sh'
```

will signal the right job. I mean: unless the right job is gone and some other job matches; but *you* should know what you have run. If the jobspec matches zero or multiple jobs then no job will be addressed.

In some circumstances also this approach may not be perfect. A parent process (here: the shell) receives `SIGCHLD` when its child (here: `nohup`) changes state. This way Bash will know if `nohup` (or anything that replaced it) exits; then it considers the job done. Grandchildren and their existence are irrelevant. If `nohup` spawns `script.sh` as another PID and exits (uncommon) or if `script.sh` replaces `nohup`, runs something asynchronously and exits, then the job will formally be done and from now on `kill '%nohup script.sh'` will address nothing (again: unless some other job matches), even if there are still grandchildren in the process group of the job.

If job control is disabled, then signalling a jobspec (e.g. `kill %3`) will address only the process (e.g. `nohup`, or `script.sh` that replaced `nohup`), not a process group.

A quite reliable way is to:

- Enable job control. Not needed if killing `script.sh` *alone* is enough (e.g. the script does not spawn long-running children). Job control is enabled by default in interactive shells. In a non-interactive Bash (e.g. in another script that is about to call `nohup script.sh &`) you can enable it by invoking `set -m` (but then signalling the process group of the outer script will not send signals to its job(s)).
- Use `nohup` that replaces itself with whatever it is told to run (e.g. `script.sh`). Your `nohup` most likely works this way.
- Make `script.sh` wait for its children (by running commands synchronously; by `wait`ing for its jobs). Not needed if killing `script.sh` alone is enough.
- Use a proper jobspec with the `kill` builtin, e.g. `kill '%nohup script.sh'`. Even `kill %3` is safer than `kill -- -31421`. A jobspec like `%3` can be reused, but it can only be reused if the relevant shell starts a new job. If you know `%3` is the right job and you don't start another job in the shell, then `kill %3` will send signals to processes in the right job, or it will fail if the job is already done. On the other hand, even if you know `31421` is the right P(G)ID, it may die and the number may be reused before you invoke `kill`; then you will (try to) send signals to some random process(es).

So jobspecs are better than PGIDs, if only they can be used. [The main reason](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3886/108618) to use `nohup script.sh` is making `script.sh` survive after you disconnect or (in case of asynchronous `nohup`) gracefully exit the shell. After you reconnect, you will find yourself in a new shell. Children of the old shell may have survived, but they will not become jobs of the new shell. Any solution that uses jobspecs is useless in the new shell. Using PID or PGID is still an option, somewhat flawed though, as the ID may have been reused (and note `pid` as a variable is gone with the old shell, you should have stored it's content somewhere).

---

#### Cgroups

In general the most reliable way would be to use [control groups (cgroups)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt). You can put `nohup` and all its children in a separate control group that cannot be mistaken with any other group. You need root access to set a custom cgroup and let your regular user own it; then you (as the regular user) can place process(es) in the control group.

It's an advanced feature, in your case most likely an overkill, not convenient for ad-hoc usage; therefore I will not elaborate.

---

#### Other possibilities

1. [I use `tmux`](https://superuser.com/a/1398132/432690) wherever I can (the alternative is `screen`). If I were you I would first think of running `script.sh` (without `nohup`; with redirections, if needed) in an interactive shell in a dedicated pane. My shell is Bash. Bash in the chosen pane would run `script.sh` in a separate process group, in the foreground. Normally <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> makes the terminal (here: `tmux`) send `SIGINT` to the foreground process group; I would make use of it if I wanted. Very convenient. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and the whole job control would work, even after reconnecting and reattaching to `tmux`.
2. [Task Spooler](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/tsp.1.html) (under the name `ts` or `tsp`) manages and runs jobs (its own kind of jobs, not jobs of the shell). It can be used instead of `nohup`. Notes:

   - It's a queue, so (depending on previous jobs and options you use) a new job may be postponed.
   - The same queue is available from all your shells, even after you reconnect. Sometimes an advantage, other times a disadvantage.

Answer (score 0):

What about simply

```
echo $$ >> running_scripts
```

This works fine for me:

```
#nohup script.sh > output.log &
[1] 48449
#ps
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
  47859 pts/12   00:00:00 tcsh
  48449 pts/12   00:00:00 sh
  48457 pts/12   00:00:00 sleep
  48458 pts/12   00:00:00 ps
#cat list_of_running_scripts 
48449
#kill 48449
#ps
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
  47859 pts/12   00:00:00 tcsh
  48494 pts/12   00:00:00 ps
[1]  + Terminated                    script.sh > output.log
```