# Make ctrl + c ask for confirmation before killing git

Tags: linux, terminal, git

I have the bad habit of killing programs when they are running because of impatience. For 99% of what I do this doesn;t cause issues because my programs don;t tend to edit files.

However git becomes dangerously corrupted when you do that. I have spent hours correcting a problem that happens in seconds through ctrl + c.

I would like for the terminal to ask me "are you sure you want to kill this program that will make your life miserable if you kill it before it finishes?"

Is it possible?

Comment: Put a piece of rubber or soft plastic foam under the Ctrl key; it will require more pressure to use and serves as a tactile reminder. The alternative is to *rewrite* git yourself. If you're not capable of doing so, hire someone who is.

Comment: I suspect ther may be alternatives, like aliasing the ctrl + C keycombination

Comment: There are already questions about remapping keys. If your question is just about remapping keys then right now it is a duplicate of those.

Comment: It's a question about how to solve the above problem through software. remapping keycombinations to a script is merely a possible approach that came to mind but not the one I would prefer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The mechanism

The terminal itself is not directly aware what processes receive `SIGINT` upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. [It sends the signal to the foreground process group](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149756/108618). Then it's the kernel who delivers the signal to each member of the group. Usually there's also a shell, but the shell does not relay the signal; it only informs the terminal which process group is in the foreground.

This mechanism allows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to interrupt all processes in a foreground pipeline. All the terminal knows is PGID (process group ID) of the current foreground process group.

---

#### Modifying terminal

You can modify the terminal, so if it's about to send `SIGINT`, it will check if there's `git` in the foreground process group and act accordingly. (I think you need to modify the tty/pts driver rather than your favorite terminal emulator; but it's way beyond my expertise, so I may be wrong.)

---

#### Modifying shell

If the shell relayed `SIGINT`, you could modify its code to ask for confirmation before relaying to `git` (or to a process group containing `git`). But the shell does not relay the signal. To relay the signal, a modified shell should always place itself alone in the foreground (so `SIGINT` from the terminal goes only to the shell) and handle an additional level of foreground-background abstraction to always be able to tell which process group it should relay the signal to. Such naive approach would not be enough (investigate `SIGTTIN` and `SIGTTOU`), the shell should provide a [pts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21280/108618). Providing a pts is what terminal multiplexers already do.

---

#### Terminal multiplexer

I'm not familiar with `screen`, I use `tmux`. The tool is [useful](https://superuser.com/a/1492018/432690) [by itself](https://superuser.com/a/1398132/432690), but now the most important thing is it can solve your problem.

Add this line to your `.tmux.conf`:

```
bind -T root 'C-c' if-shell 'tty="#{pane_tty}"; ps -eo tty,stat,comm | grep "^${tty#/dev/} .*+.* git$"' 'confirm-before -p "Git detected. Confirm SIGINT? (y/n)" "send-keys C-c"' 'send-keys C-c'
```

Notes:

- I tested this with `sleep`, not `git` (because I don't use `git`).
- `ps -o stat` is not portable. I used `ps` from `procps-ng 3.3.15` on Debian 10. `stat` is useful because it prints `+` for processes in foreground process groups. The idea is to ignore `git` in the background (if any) because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> won't send `SIGINT` to it anyway.

This solution is my personal choice (partially because I use `tmux` daily). **It's the only solution in my answer that actually asks for confirmation.**

---

#### Modifying `git`

You can modify `git` to behave differently. I don't necessarily mean Git (i.e. the tool, although modifying it is also possible), but the command. You can create a wrapper script or a shell function named `git` that would:

- run the real `git` in a way that would make it ignore `SIGINT`,
- or run the real `git` in yet another process group that is never in the foreground,
- or reconfigure the controlling terminal, run the real `git`, configure the terminal back.

Below are example functions, tested in Bash. If you decide to create a wrapper script (instead of a function) under the name `git` and available via `PATH`, then use a full path to the real `git` to avoid the script calling itself.

---

To make the real `git` ignore `SIGINT`, wrap it in the following function:

```
git () ( trap '' INT; exec git "$@" )
```

Note the function body runs in a subshell, so `trap` will not affect the main shell. There are disadvantages:

- The real `git` will ignore every `SIGINT` (it will not ignore `SIGTERM` though).
- If `git` is used in a pipeline then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will still affect other parts of it. Then the real `git` may exit anyway because of `SIGPIPE`. We could `trap '' PIPE` as well, but I guess you'd like not to interrupt the pipe in the first place.

---

Running the real `git` in yet another process group (no matter how you do it) is IMO not better, sometimes worse than the above "ignore `SIGINT`" solution.

---

This is how you reconfigure the terminal back and forth:

```
git () ( trap '' INT; stty -F /dev/tty intr '^G'; ( trap - INT; exec git "$@" ); stty -F /dev/tty intr '^C' )
```

Now as long as `git` runs, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will not work; use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> instead if your really want to interrupt it.

Notes:

- If `git` is used in a pipeline then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will not affect other parts of it. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> will affect the whole pipeline.
- If you run `git` (the wrapper) in the background then it will be suspended immediately because of `stty` trying to interact with the controlling terminal. To circumvent, you can start `git` in the foreground and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> after the first `stty` runs, then `bg`. On <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> the shell may restore tty settings (Bash does), which is fortunate if you plan to `bg`; but if you `fg` then you will be able to terminate the real `git` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> again.
- If there are two or more `git`s in a foreground pipeline then the first one to exit will restore the default setting, while you would certainly prefer only the last one to do it.