# How can I make `clear` preserve entire scrollback buffer?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

Whenever I run `clear` in my terminal, it deletes the scrollback buffer from the top of visible part of the screen to the current line. I have tried it in multiple terminal emulators and the problem remains. Is there any way I can change the behavior of `clear` so it does not touch the scrollback buffer?

My terminal before `clear` command:

[image: terminal before "clear" command]

Scrollback buffer after `clear` command

[image: scrollback buffer after "clear" command]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Analysis

You call the behavior "weird" but it's by design. `clear` does not move text out of the screen, it actually *clears* what's on the screen. Strictly it only tells the terminal (terminal emulator) to do it.

In some terminals `clear` effectively clears the entire scrollback buffer. At least `clear` in my Kubuntu does it; with `-x` I can ask it not to. See `man 1 clear`.

My `$TERM` is `xterm-256color` and this is how `clear` works for me:

```
$ clear | od -c
0000000 033   [   H 033   [   2   J 033   [   3   J
0000013
$ clear -x | od -c
0000000 033   [   H 033   [   2   J
0000007
```

`clear -x` is equivalent to `printf '\033[H\033[2J'`,
sole `clear` is equivalent to `printf '\033[H\033[2J\033[3J'`.

These sequences are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences). The terminal is supposed to interpret them.

|  | Abbr | Name | Effect |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `CSI n ; m H` | CUP | Cursor Position | Moves the cursor to row `n`, column `m`. […] |
| `CSI n J` | ED | Erase in Display | Clears part of the screen. […] |

Note what `clear` prints strongly depends on `$TERM`. E.g. if I pick a "random" terminal:

```
$ TERM=ztx clear | od -c
0000000 033   E
0000002
```

The above `clear` does not use ED; it uses CNL:

|  | Abbr | Name | Effect |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `CSI n E` | CNL | Cursor Next Line | Moves cursor to beginning of the line `n` (default `1`) lines down. […] |

which does not clear the screen in my terminal. *Maybe* it does in a real `ztx`; or it doesn't, I don't know. Anyway `clear` "thinks" the terminal is `ztx` and for `ztx` CNL is the best choice.

In any case we could build and use an equivalent `printf` command. The very point of `clear` is it checks `$TERM` in the environment and then looks in the terminfo database (see `man 5 terminfo`) to determine how to clear the screen. With `printf` we would need to do this manually.

It's not impossible some implementation(s) of `clear` in some circumstances (i.e. for some value of `$TERM`) print a sequence that does what you want.

And then there is the terminal (terminal emulator). Even if `clear` prints `\033[2J`, the terminal may *react* by doing what you want. Maybe there is an option that lets you choose. You can write a terminal emulator that reacts this way.

I often use tmux, it implements its own scrollback buffer. Inside it `$TERM` expands to `screen`; `clear` and `clear -x` are both equivalent to `printf '\033[H\033[J'`. This sequence does what you want when interpreted by tmux. But outside of tmux (in my case with scrollback buffer provided by Konsole) the same sequence replicates your problem. I deduce tmux is a terminal emulator that reacts the way you want.

My point is: `clear` prints different things, depending on what it "thinks" your terminal is; then the terminal interprets these things and it may react in whatever way. E.g. your `clear` seems to do what my `clear -x` does: it does not clear the entire scrollback buffer, only the visible part. So maybe your `clear` does not print `\033[3J`; or maybe it does but your terminal does not clear the buffer fully anyway.

*Maybe* you could find a different value of `$TERM` so *your* `clear` consulting *your* terminfo database will be able to make *your* terminal emulator do what you want. Even if you could do this, I wouldn't say it's the Right Thing in general. Changing `$TERM` can break other things.

---

#### Solution 1: tmux

Use tmux and its scrollback buffer. My tests indicate it behaves the way you want (at least when `clear` sees `$TERM` as `screen`). The tool is a terminal multiplexer, I use it routinely because of its [other](https://superuser.com/a/1398132/432690) [features](https://superuser.com/a/1492018/432690) and I had to explicitly get out of it to write some parts of this answer.

It may be a major change in how you work in terminals. In my *opinion* it's worth it. Note using the scrollback buffer of tmux is in many aspects different than using the scrollback buffer of a terminal emulator.

Consider at least trying tmux.

---

#### Solution 2: custom `clear` as a shell function

It seems you don't want to clear anything; you want to move text out of the screen and place the prompt at the top. So let's do this:

```sh
clear() (
   if [ "$#" -ne 0 ]; then
      command clear "$@"
      exit
   fi
   h="$(tput lines 2>/dev/null)"
   if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
      until [ "$h" -le 1 ]; do
         printf '\n'
         h=$((h-1))
      done
   fi
   command clear -x
)
```

The function overrides the `clear` command when invoked without arguments; it falls back to the command otherwise. When it overrides, the function prints just the right number of newlines to move the previous content out of the screen; then regular `clear -x` is invoked to clear the newlines and place the prompt at the top.

Notes:

- `tput lines` is not portable. If there is any problem with this command then the function will only call `command clear -x`.
- `command clear -x` assumes your `clear` executable supports `-x` like mine does. Judging by the question you don't need `-x`, your sole `clear` does not clear the entire buffer (maybe because your `clear` is different; maybe because your terminal(s) are different). It may be enough to call `printf '\033[H\033[2J'` instead. On the other hand `command clear …` consults the terminfo database, it's a feature one may want from the function as well. Adjust the function to your needs.
- If the terminal emulator is resized when the function works then the function may misbehave. If you need to resize, do it before or after calling `clear`, not during.
- The function can be used inside tmux. It's absolutely not needed there (because tmux itself is a solution) but as far as I can tell it doesn't break anything. So e.g. you can place the function in your `~/.bashrc` in case you use Bash outside of tmux, and still the things should work fine when you use Bash inside tmux.
- Any shell function is defined in a shell. Our code can be converted to a script (wrapper) that overrides `clear` regardless of the shell.

Comment: thanks a lot. but **what is the difference between `clear -x` and the bash script you have mentioned?** and yes `clear -x` works differently in different terminal emulators. In gnome-terminal it works fine but in kitty terminal `clear` and `clear -x` have the same result.

Comment: @Manoj The only script I have mentioned is a wrapper (yet to be created) that would do what the function does. So are you asking what the difference between `clear -x` and the function is? E.g. for me in `konsole`, outside of `tmux`, when `$TERM` expands to `xterm-256color`, `clear -x` removes what's on the screen from the scrollbuffer. So it's *exactly* your issue. The function solves the issue. `clear` without `-x` (the command, not the function) clears the screen and the entire scrollbuffer. From the three only the function preserves the entire scrollbuffer.

Comment: but can't we just use an alias `alias clear="clear -x"`. how ever i am using kitty, `clear -x` gives the same result as `clear` but your script works fine. than you for your time.

Comment: @Manoj If you use `alias clear="clear -x"` then `clear` will work like `clear -x` which in some terminals *does not* solve the issue. Where `clear -x` solves the issue (if anywhere), the function will also solve it. Where `clear -x` does not solve the issue, the function may solve it. Konsole in my Kubuntu is an example of a terminal emulator where `clear -x` does not solve the issue, yet the function does.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - the `clear()` function works wonderfully when I type out `clear` inside my terminal. However when I map it to a keyboard shortcut, it gets executed in the background and doesn't clear the active terminal I'm looking at. Is there a way to modify it so that it detects the "current" or "active" terminal and executes it there? Thanks again!

Comment: @user2490003 Ask a new question maybe. Include a link to this one to provide context. Explain how exactly you "map it to a keyboard shortcut". State your shell.

Comment: I wonder why the Form-Feed character doesn't do the job. I would expect a terminal to at least support what printers supported before terminals came to replace them.

Answer (score 1):

From the man page, `clear -x` does not clear the scrollback buffer.

Comment: `clear -x` in my case has the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Short, portable answer:

`tput indn $LINES`
... will scroll the current terminal "up" by the amount of lines it has.
The effect is a "clear" of the screen, without loss of any scroll buffer content.

And as shown elsewhere:
`tput indn $LINES | od -t x1z`
... will display what exactly is happening *(in hex, with a character interpretation here)*.

*`man terminfo`* for more options to tput.

This is perfectly possible to put in an alias or even a bash function.

```
function scroll_up {
  tput indn $LINES
}
```

---

NOTE: `shopt -s checkwinsize` (more info; man bash) should be in your `$HOME/.bashrc` or `$HOME/.bash_aliases` - just as the `scroll_up` function above.

One more NOTE:
To extend portability make sure to instead of `shopt ...` use
`LINES=$(tput lines)`

Comment: In what sense is `$LINES` portable? AFAIK POSIX acknowledges the variable and its meaning but it *does not* require it to be set in the first place. I'm not saying the answer is wrong (although in Konsole I do lose lines from the scrollback buffer); I'm not convinced it's portable.

Comment: Nitpicking? Right: The word "portable" might not apply to the $LINES variable, I believe terminfo OTOH is a good candidate there.

Comment: note `tput lines` and ... columns.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48016366/3720510