# How do I stop programs from clearing iTerm2's scrollback buffer?

Tags: terminal, scrolling, iterm2

I never under any circumstances want some random program to send an escape code and clear the scrollback buffer in iTerm2. (In the unlikely event that I want the scrollback buffer gone, I'm perfectly capable of handling that myself.) How do I disable this misfeature?

(An example of this occurring is zsh's new profile wizard, `zsh-newuser-install`, using `clear`. Presumably any number of other programs on any number of ssh-connected computers could do the same thing, so iTerm2 itself must be corrected. Otherwise I would just refer to [How can I make `clear` preserve entire scrollback buffer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1667569/how-can-i-make-clear-preserve-entire-scrollback-buffer))