# Clearing the terminal without deleting anything

Tags: terminal

In my case `clear` actually deletes all onscreen output. What I want is a way to start off with a clear terminal while still having access to all prior output by scrolling up.

I use Kitty and Fish btw.

Comment: Similar: [*How can I make `clear` preserve entire scrollback buffer?*](https://superuser.com/q/1667569/432690)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clear -x` to preserve the scrollback buffer, or CTRL+L keypress.

You could e.g. alias something like `cls` to `'clear  -x'` so you have two commands available, to either clear the buffer or not.

Both these work in Kitty 0.76.1.13, when I use it to SSH into Bash (or Fish 3.0.2) on a Debian remote computer.

Comment: In my case `clear -x` does not delete the *scrollback* buffer but it does delete the output that is currently on screen, meaning that content is no longer available in the scrollback afterwards.

Comment: How odd. If I do `clear -x` I produce a clear screen, the cursor goes to the top of the terminal, and if I scroll up the first line that comes into view (the last line of the scroll buffer contents) is... the `clear -x` that I entered. Thus nothing that was on the screen before is lost. This is the same in bash and fish. Still using kitty. One difference with CTR+L (instead of clear -x) is that an extra blank line appears at the end of the buffer on scrolling up.