# Can I show multiple tmux sessions in one pane?

Tags: linux, shell, tmux

I have 5 node js scripts running, each in their own tmux session. I saw something completely unrelated a few days ago where someone was using tmux and they had like 6 different shells open on the same screen through tmux but I don't know what he was doing so maybe it's not what I think it is.

Is it possible for me to monitor all 5 of those sessions I created at the same time by putting them into a window like that? All I can find on google is how to create a new window but that doesn't directly answer my question.

I want a single view that will show me all 5 sessions at the same time so I don't need to attach to one at a time to see the current output.

EDIT: **Workflow**

TMUX session was created by doing `tmux new-session -t app1`
`tmux new-session -t app2` `tmux new-session -t app3` `tmux new-session -t app4` `tmux new-session -t app5`

`tmux attach-session -t app1`

`cd /srv/myapp1/`

`node express.js`

CTRL+B CTRL+D

`tmux attach-session -t app2`

`cd /srv/myapp2/`

`node express.js`

CTRL+B CTRL+D

....And so on for all 5 apps.

I would prefer to create a single pane of my already existing sessions but I can restart them if needed. I want to view a single pane and see the output of all 5 sessions at once.

Comment: "6 different shells open on the same screen through tmux but I don't know what he was doing so" – [Splitting a tmux window to multiple panes is one of the basic features](https://superuser.com/a/1398132). (1) So you have multiple tmux sessions (within one tmux server, right?), each with a single window with a single pane (right?) and you want to show them as one window, right? (2) Do you need this for already running sessions? or will you accept a solution for future use, where you create separate panes within one window, instead of separate sessions? (3) Or must (the) sessions stay separate?

Comment: Please respond to the above by [edit]ing and clarifying the question. Do not respond in comments.

Comment: Posting command(s) you use to run "5 node js scripts", "each in their own tmux session" may help. Show us your workflow, options you use and such.

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: So you do it by hand, basically. In tmux experiment with `Ctrl+b, "`, `Ctrl+b, %`, `Ctrl+b, {`, `Ctrl+b, }`, `Ctrl+b, arrows` and `Ctrl+b, z`; are you familiar with them? Then it should be quite obvious how to run 5x `node express.js` in one tmux window *anew*. Do you need help in rearranging *already running* separate tmux sessions to a single tmux window?